# Is it programatically illegal to make a seperate Main Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

My contacts list in Android Studio has a "Remove Contacts" tab that works as a Main Activity, having a `Main_Remove_Contact` class and a `Remove_Contact` class.

I would like to know if it's wrong to make a class that would be a Main Class in another project, but not on this one; can the app withstand a Main Activity and a "Main Activity"-like class. I'm saying this because of this **error**:

```
2022-02-09 08:36:32.966 6840-6840/com.example.wolfixfinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wolfixfinal, PID: 6840
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data from pid=6840, uid=10160 requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:599)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:576)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:564)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:2196)
        at com.example.wolfixfinal.Main_Remove_Contact.onOptionsItemSelected(Main_Remove_Contact.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4269)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:66)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:221)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:975)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

One of the lines says

`at com.example.wolfixfinal.Main_Remove_Contact.onOptionsItemSelected(Main_Remove_Contact.java:55)`

The code of the method where the line is is the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                showContacts();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_check:
                for(int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
                    listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(ContactsContract.Data._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(item)}).build());
                try {
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`.applyBatch` (in the try catch segment) is where the error is at. Does it have to do with the aforementioned Main Activity problem, or is it something else (it could be an outdated resource).

**TL;DR:**

- Question in the title
- Is `applyBatch` outdated?
- If not, how does it work in the method inserted above?

If more code is needed in the `Main_Remove_Class` activity, I'll edit the question. It does get some attributes from `Remove_Class` but I don't know if they're needed.

I think this question could also help with some specific *IntelliJ Idea* key-words, so I'll add that as a tag too. I might make a specific question about `.applyBatch` too if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I already have the permission that asks the app if it can read contacts (`android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`).

Comment: `that works as a Main Activity,` what does this mean ? the word `Main Activity` doesn't carry any significant meaning, it's just the default activity set in the manifest. it's very difficult to answer what you're asking, because you're also asking several questions at once. `Is it programatically illegal to make a seperate Main Activity in Android Studio?` lots of apps have more than one activity

Comment: Well, if Main Activities don't have any difference from normal activities, then forget I said that because I actually didn't know that. But if that's not the problem, then why does this code work in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uS7cVb9WBNA&ab_channel=EDMTDev, but not in mine. Like I said at the end, it might just be the `.applyBatch` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Those activities are all fine.

You need to ask the user to grant the `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` runtime permission for writing contacts:

This is the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/data from pid=6840, uid=10160 requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

Dangerous permissions like `WRITE_CONTACTS` require you to ask the user for a permission at runtime. This means, just declaring the permission in the android manifest file is not enough.

Check out the guide on [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: I already did in manifest.xml. That's not why this error shows up. That's why this question is so extensive.

Comment: @André_Almeida I updated my answer. Adding the WRITE_CONTACTS permission to the manifest isn't enough to use it.

Comment: So is there another way? Or are contact apps unable to do that anymore, because I just want to make the APP not able to see those contacts, or at least the user not able to see the other contacts in the app.

Comment: The alternative is to use an intent with [SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents#SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT). If a contact app is installed, the android OS will open the default contact app and allow the user to add a contact from there with the data that you provide. This doesn't require runtime permissions.